# tool(s) for exporting and comparing html dom structure

Tags: html, dom

I have 2 sites with slightly different code (one is static from design, the other has code for a dynamic page for production). The static site is working ok, the other has some layout issues. Suspect this is an issue on the DOM as the CSS appears to be the same. The production site has slightly different results in IE, FF and Chrome and using the developer tools I can't see any difference in the DOM from the site that works.

Are there any tools where I can export the DOM structure from both pages, then do a compare of the DOM to see if there are any differences? Doing a diff of the actual page source isn't much use as the design site has different text content.

Answer (score 0):

Well i would suggest give a try to [Page Diff addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pagediff/)

Other than thats you can use WinMerge or Beyond compare to do the same purpose

Comment: Looking for a DOM diff, not a text diff